# Does "VerifyTests / Verify" have global settings?

Tags: verify, verify-tests

@Simon (https://stackoverflow.com/users/53158/simon)

In the [docs](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/blob/main/docs/naming.md#directory) it is mentioned how to setup a custom output directory for `Verify` and it works fine, but it is pain to do it for every test.

```cs
await Verify("value")
    .UseDirectory("CustomDirectory");
```

ApprovalTests have a global `UseApprovalSubdirectory` which solves this issue. So I wonder is there anything similar in [VerifyTests / Verify](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify)?
The reason is that VS2022 does not allow renaming nested files, so I need to go to the file explorer and rename files there (pain...)

Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/issues/482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to use [DerivePathInfo](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/blob/main/docs/naming.md#derivepathinfo) to achieve this. So in your case

```
VerifierSettings.DerivePathInfo(
    (sourceFile, projectDirectory, type, method) =>
    {
        return new(
            directory: Path.Combine(projectDirectory, "CustomDirectory"),
            typeName: type.Name,
            methodName: method.Name);
    });
```